# I can't seem to add to the array generated by serializeArray

Tags: javascript, jquery, serializearray

Here's the code.

```
        var postData={};
    event.stopPropagation();
    postData.action='preview';
    postData.data=$("form#gaarrl").serializeArray();
    var n=[];
    n['name']='media';
    n['value']=imgName;
    postData.data.push(n);       
    console.dir(postData);
    $.post("database.php",{postData },
```

The console.dir command shows the media:imgName as a part of the postData.data as expected but the database.php $_REQUEST only shows the elements from the serializeArray step.

What is happening?

Thanks,
Jim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `var n = [];` to `var n = {};`.

This fixed it for me.

This is because normal Javascript arrays do not allow keys, just numerical indexes. `{}` is shorthand for `new Object()`, and allows you to give it multiple named attributes.

Comment: Of course!  Thank you for that.  Sometimes the simplest things trip us up.